# How do I log contents of a JSONP

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, get, jsonp

I have the following js code to retrieve a response object from a RESTful api. I tried doing a console log just to see the contents of the response object, however I see nothing logged in the console. But when I check my network tab, the response object is there. What am I doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://mylocaldotcom/products",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(products) { console.log(products); }
});
```

Comment: Does the API respond with an actual JSONP script? Just a JSON object won't be enough.

Comment: It only returns a JSON object. I am trying to do a work around for Cross-Origin Request

Comment: Well you can't just "work around it", the *server* needs to support JSONP or CORS or whatever. The only thing you can do if you don't control the API is a proxy.